# MongoDB database connection is not working in express with mongoose

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to connect mongoDB database with my app but can not be succeeded. I followed another answers related to this but failed that is why I asked here.

This is an old project. It needs to connect and run remaining the old packages versions right now. The project is at a running stage and now needs to connect with `mongodb` database

The code example as like below:

**package.json**

```
 {
  "name": "...",
  "description": "Full-Stack JavaScript with MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, and Node.js",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "...",
  "engines": {
    "node": "4.4.4",
    "npm": "3.8.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "grunt",
    "debug": "grunt debug",
    "test": "grunt test",
    "postinstall": "bower install --config.interactive=false"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "~0.9.0",
    "body-parser": "~1.9.0",
    "bower": "~1.3.8",
    "chalk": "~0.5",
    "compression": "~1.2.0",
    "connect-flash": "~0.1.1",
    "connect-mongo": "^1.1.0",
    "consolidate": "~0.10.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.2",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "express-session": "^1.13.0",
    "forever": "~0.11.0",
    "glob": "~4.0.5",
    "gridfs-stream": "^1.1.1",
    "grunt-cli": "~0.1.13",
    "helmet": "~0.5.0",
    "lodash": "^4.12.0",
    "method-override": "~2.3.0",
    "mongoose": "4.4.16",
    "morgan": "~1.4.1",
    "multer": "^1.1.0",
    "nodemailer": "~2.4.1",
    "passport": "~0.2.0",
    "passport-facebook": "~1.0.2",
    "passport-github": "~0.1.5",
    "passport-google-oauth": "~0.1.5",
    "passport-linkedin": "~0.1.3",
    "passport-local": "~1.0.0",
    "passport-twitter": "~1.0.2",
    "paypal-rest-sdk": "^1.6.8",
    "q": "^1.5.1",
    "stripe": "^4.6.0",
    "swig": "~1.4.1",
    "validator": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^2.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-csslint": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-env": "^0.4.4",
    "grunt-karma": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-mocha-test": "^0.12.7",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "^2.0.2",
    "grunt-nodemon": "^0.4.2",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^0.1.7",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^3.5.0",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "should": "^8.3.1",
    "supertest": "^1.2.0"
  }
}
```

**server.js**

```
    var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://<username>:<password>@cluster0.qlvoh.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority',   function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(chalk.red('Could not connect to MongoDB!'));
        console.log(chalk.red(err));
    } else {
        console.log('Connection Successful');
    }
}, {useMongoClient: true});
```

I used right username, password and db name and tested on `mongodb-compass`. It connects in `mongodb-compass` successfully. So the username and password are correct indeed.

When I use `mongodb+srv://...` in the `uri` string, the console error is like;

```
[nodemon] 1.19.4
    [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
    [nodemon] watching dir(s): app/views/**/*.* gruntfile.js server.js config/**/*.js app/**/*.js
    [nodemon] watching extensions: js,html
    [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
    NODE_ENV is not defined! Using default development environment
    Could not connect to MongoDB!
    Error: Invalid mongodb uri. Must begin with "mongodb://"
      Received: ...
      .../node_modules/gridfs-stream/lib/index.js:25
      if (!db) throw new Error('missing db argument\nnew Grid(db, mongo)');
               ^
    
    Error: missing db argument
    new Grid(db, mongo)
```

So I use `mongodb://` in connection string and then it returns `Could not connect to MongoDB!` as follows:
[image: Could not connect to MongoDB!]

Noted that the `mongoose` version is `4.4.16`.

When I use `mongoose` version 5 or higher, it returns an error from `node_modules/connect-mongo` as follow:

```
...node_modules/connect-mongo/src/index.js:105
                    throw new Error('Connection strategy not found');
                    ^
    
    Error: Connection strategy not found
        at new MongoStore...
```

Anyone help me please to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Mongoose version is very old (the 6.2.x is the latest). Are you able to connect to the database server from any other tools, like, `mongosh` or Compass?

Comment: Yes, I connected to the database server from Compass tool successfully and checked again right now using the same uri string with username, password and dbname. That is why my concern is why it can not be connected with mongoose

Comment: Maybe use a newer version of Mongoose.

Comment: That means there is no solution keeping the current mongoose version 4.4.16, right?
Actually, this is an old project where there are many old packages. If I update one package, another dependency comes into affects. The app is running currently and just database connection is needed as well.

Comment: I dont know for sure its the version issue. But, it could be. You can try a simple connection test with new version and see if it works.

Comment: try using `useNewUrlParser: true`

Comment: @SureshPrajapati I checked using `useNewUrlParser: true` right now. 
Same here

`NODE_ENV is not defined! Using default development environment
    MEAN.JS application started on port 3000
    Could not connect to MongoDB!
    MongoError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND cluster0.qlvoh.mongodb.net cluster0.qlvoh.mongodb.net:27017`

Comment: @prasad_  I checked with fewer mongoose version 5 or higher, it returns an error from `node_modules/connect-mongo` as `Error: Connection strategy not found`

Comment: I resolved my connection issue adding the connection string uri from MongoDB atlas with selecting only node version 2.2.12 or later option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to connect successfully with only selecting `node 2.2.12 or later` option from `MongoDB atlas` account.

[image: connection string uri]

And the string `uri` is as like below:

```
mongodb://<username>:<password>@cluster0-shard-0000.vnrr0.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01.vnrr0.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02.vnrr0.mongodb.net:27017/myFirstDatabase?ssl=true&replicaSet=atlas-134hkh-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority
```